# Alert me a message if i enter the same name or word in one search bar or text box twice using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="medicineSearchBar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
            <ul style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow-y: scroll;" id="li-psearch" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"
                aria-labelledby="menu1">
                <li role="presentation" class="divider-search"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alert me a message if i enter the same name or word  in one search bar or text box  using jQuery or javascript 
The word or name is coming from json file

Comment: then show you json structure first

Comment: @BeingSunny ["Genouillère renforcée ($30)","Genouillère Small ($20)","Genouillères XXL ($20)","Knee brace long type ($50)","Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)","Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)","Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)","Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)","Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)","Sac de sable de 500g ($25)","Slip orthopédique ($70)"]